# insert value in middle of every value inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a array has a value of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` now I want it to become a object that have it's value so I do some array mapping

```
const arrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
let arrObj = arrs.map(arr => {
    return {value: arr}
})
```

Now the value of `arrObj` is

```
[{value: 'a'}, {value: 'b'}, {value: 'c'}, {value: 'd'}, {value: 'e'}]
```

But what I want to do is to insert a object in the middle of each object that is inside the array that has a value of `{operator: '+'}` so the value of `arrObj` will be

```
[{value: 'a'}, {operator: '+'}, {value: 'b'}, {operator: '+'}, {value: 'c'}, {operator: '+'}, {value: 'd'}, {operator: '+'}, {value: 'e'}]
```

now, using javascript, how can I achive that function given that I'm setting a value of arrObj in array.map() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new array with a double length minus one and add the required values, depending on the index.

```js
var values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    result = Array.from(
        { length: values.length * 2 - 1 },
        (_, i) => i % 2
            ? { operator: '+' }
            : { value: values[i >> 1] }
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I don't have an idea how this works, but it definitely solve my problem

Comment: Can you please tell how the `i >> 1` shift operator works here?

Comment: @adiga, it's a short writing for getting the integer half of the index, traditional like this: `Math.floor(i / 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to map each element (but the last) to an array with that element and another with the `+`, then flatten:

```js
const arrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const transformed = arrs
  .map((char, i) => (
    i === arrs.length - 1
    ? [{ value: char }]
    : [{ value: char }, { value: '+' }]
  ))
  .flat();
console.log(transformed);
```

If `+` won't appear in the input array, then you can join by `+` initially, then split:

```js
const arrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const output = arrs
  .join('+')
  .split('')
  .map(value => ({ value }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: the first answer returned an error saying `arrs.map(...).flat is not a function` so I removed the .flat() and it returns an array of array that has a value of `[ [ { value: 'a' }, { operator: '+' } ],  [ { value: 'b' }, { operator: '+' } ] ... ]`

Comment: on the second answer, the name of the additional data that will be putting inside object must have been a name of `operator` like `{operator: '+'}`

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap` and return a pair from the callback. Finally, remove the extra element.

```js
const arrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

let arrObj = arrs.flatMap(x => [
    {operator: '+'}, {value: x}
]).slice(1)

console.log(arrObj)
```

If your platform doesn't have `flatMap` yet, it's trivial to polyfill:

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(fn) {
    return this.concat.apply([], this.map(fn))
}
```

Generic function:

```
let interleave = (ary, val) => ary.flatMap(x => [val, x]).slice(1);

//

let arrObj = interleave(
    arrs.map(x => ( {value: x})),
    {operator: '+'}
)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that `arrs.flatMap is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

What about using reduce?

```
 let arrObj = arrs.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
        if (index === arrs.length - 1) acc = [...acc, {value: curr}];
        else acc = [...acc, {value: curr}, {operator: '+'}];
        return acc;
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat your required object and deep flatten it like below:

```js
var arrs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e'];
const arrObj = arrs.map((arr,i) => {
 let item = [{value: arr}];
  if(i < arrs.length-1)
   item.push({operator: '+'});
  return item;
});
console.log(flattenDeep(arrObj));

function flattenDeep(arr1) {
       return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
    }
```

For more details take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: The excepted output doesn't end with a `"operator": "+"` object

Comment: @adiga, I have updated the answer to match with the expected output.